# How to query and select embedded id column

Tags: java, jpa, hql, composite-key

I have two class in java which is txn and txnID, I want to retrieve txnid value from embedded table, below is my txn class structure :

```
public class TbTxn implements Serializable{

@EmbeddedId
private TbTxnId id;

private Long   acctid;
private String hmbrchcd;
private String crdno;
//all the getter and setter code
}
```

here is the embedded class structure :

```
@Embeddable
public class TbTxnId implements Serializable{

private Date txndttm;
private Long txnid;

@Column(name="TXNDTTM")
public Date getTxndttm() {
    return txndttm;
}
 public void setTxndttm(Date txndttm) {
    this.txndttm = txndttm;
}

 @Column(name="TXNID")
public Long getTxnid() {
    return txnid;
}
public void setTxnid(Long txnid) {
    this.txnid = txnid;
}
}
```

my query statement as below :

```
String stmt = "select txn.id.TXNID from TbTxn txn where txn.id.TXNDTTM >= SYSDATE ";

Long count = (Long) getSession().createQuery(stmt).uniqueResult();
```

error message below :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id.TXNID of: com.domain.TbTxn [select txn.id.TXNID from com.domain.TbTxn txn where txn.id.TXNDTTM >= SYSDATE ]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id.TXNID of: com.domain.TbTxn [select txn.id.TXNID from com.domain.TbTxn txn where txn.id.TXNDTTM >= SYSDATE ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String stmt = "select txn.id.txnid from TbTxn txn where txn.id.txndttm >= SYSDATE ";
```

We should take care of cases of entity class names and their attributes.

Comment: its not working either. got this error : expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1, column 15 [select txn.id.**TXNID** from com.domain.TbTxn txn where txn.id.TXNDTTM >= SYSDATE ]

Comment: thats work now. had follow to exact attributes name that has been declared